# What are the main arguments for slavery?

Tags: legislation, ethics

*We undoubtedly must have read and heard passionate arguments justifying the abolition of slavery, be it from the clergy, and philosophical and political clerisy; however, what has been absent from the reading list are the counter-arguments from proponents of slavery, particularly the sociologists, anthropologists, economists, psychologists, political theorists, and moral philosophers and ethicists.*

*What would be the main argument(s) justifying slavery?

Taking into account:

- arguments made that slavery can be morally defended.
- legally re-introduced into the world, under certain terms.
- ways in which people may voluntarily wish to enter into slavery.
- whether slavery is always bad, for the slave.
- benefits/desirability of slavery by both parties.

*Note: please avoid innuendo and rants, skip if prevailing dogma inhibits you from constructive engagement.*

Comment: Are you asking about past scholarly literature (as you mention reading lists)? Also, limit your question to a single question (and make separate questions if that is not possible).

Comment: @uberhaxed thanks for the feedback made some changes accordingly. Scholarly literature would be most helpful, or even your equally insightful inference from them.

Comment: [Please don't post the same question on multiple Stack Exchange sites](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/107051/52589).

Answer (score 4):

> Question:
>
> What are the main arguments for slavery?

> **Short Answer:**

History, religion, economics, the law and fear.

> Answer:

1. **History** Defenders of slavery argued that slavery had existed throughout history and was the natural state of mankind. The Greeks had slaves, the Romans had slaves, until relatively recently everybody had slaves (there perspective).
2. **Religion** Slavery was in the bible.  Abraham had slaves.

- **[Genesis 12:16](https://www.brandeis.edu/projects/fse/slavery/antiquity/docs/MoskowitzSlaverySources.pdf)**
  And for her sake he dealt well with Abram; and he had sheep, oxen, male donkeys, male and female slaves, female donkeys, and camels
- **[In the New Testament, Paul returned a runaway slave, Philemon, to his master.](https://www.fuller.edu/next-faithful-step/resources/paul-and-philemon)**
- although slavery was widespread throughout the Roman world, Jesus never spoke out against it.

3. **Economics:**

Slavery represented a lot of "capital" for the south.

4. **The Law**

**[Dred Scott Decision](https://www.sos.mo.gov/archives/resources/africanamerican/scott/scott.asp)** was law.  Not just slaves but all African Americans were not citizens,

- In its 1857 decision that stunned the nation, the United States Supreme Court upheld slavery in United States territories, denied the legality of black citizenship in America, and declared the Missouri Compromise to be unconstitutional. All of this was the result of an April 1846 action when Dred Scott innocently made his mark with an "X," signing his petition in a pro forma freedom suit, initiated under Missouri law, to sue for freedom in the St. Louis Circuit Court.

5. **Fear:**

If you free the slaves, it would bring widespread unemployment and civil unrest to people unequipped to take care of themselves.

Comment: *"Slavery represented a lot of "capital" for the south."* - why would free labour not similarly represent a capital resource "for the south" collectively? These "arguments" come across as very superficial arguments for the continuation of slavery which already exists (and avoiding transition costs, such as the need for slaves to learn how to "take care of themselves" having grown up in captivity), rather than compelling arguments for why a system of slavery should be established in the first place.

Comment: @Steve "compelling arguments for why a system of slavery should be established in the first place."* finally someone found the needle in the haystack.

Comment: *"Slavery represented a lot of "capital" for the south."* we are looking at slavery as an institution with varying actors (e.g., politicians, scientists, merchants, lawyers, etc.) not specifically through the lens of race (e.g., White, Brown, Black etc..) or nationality (e.g., English, Mexican etc..) hence why in the question, *"counter-arguments from proponents of slavery, particularly the sociologists, anthropologists, economists, psychologists, political theorists, and moral philosophers and ethicists."*

Answer (score 3):

Slavery arose as a way to make people hold non-prestigeous occupations.

Examples of these are mining, doing household chores, tending to crops at a large commercial latifundia. Also, growing non-staple crops such as sugar cane or cotton.

Contemporary examples of prestigeous occupations - having your own shop, owning a business, growing grain or cattle, military service. Often times, these occupations could be further split so that the free folk, the capital owners, were only doing prestigeous parts whereas the rest could be pushed to slaves.

Fast forward many centuries, in many modern societies we are seeing the assumption that the labor market should provide cheap, low-prestige labor. Countries are ready to either import fresh immigrants to fill these niches, or oftentimes to have an underclass native born people of immigrant background who would be coerced into manning these positions. It is covered by diversity rhetoric but the underlying demand is exactly the same as the one covered by slave labor previously.

I'm pretty confident that a lot of people and organizations feel entitled to have access to such a workforce. "If we tighten immigration laws, who would we hire to do that?"

So the frame challenge is, a lot of arguments are found when it is necessary to defend the "slave-like" occupations. This while keeping in mind that many slave-based economies had widespread phenomenon of emancipating some slaves to personal freedom, leads us to the conclusion that these arguments apply to a spectrum that includes slavery.

Comment: This is an interesting argument, but aren't these occupations low-prestige precisely because they are low-paid and done by slaves? That is, because the degree of exploitation of those in those occupations, means only severe coercion is capable of keeping those occupations filled *under those severely exploited terms*?

Comment: @Steve Mostly yes. And if the society insists on keeping these occupations lowly paid and badly treated, it implicitly argues for slavery.

Comment: Quite. The way I originally read your answer was as suggesting that certain occupations are inherently non-prestigious, and because it's reasonably necessary or socially desirable to have these occupations filled, slavery is therefore necessary. Your argument actually seems to be that occupations can occasionally become so characterised by exploitative terms, that they lose all respectability and it is no longer possible to fill them with free labour. In those cases, those benefitting from the exploitation may double down and try to impose slavery. (1/2)

Comment: The suggestion that mining is not prestigious is what caught my eye, because when mining was well-paid it was amongst the most prestigious working class jobs, because it was physically demanding and kept men fit and powerfully built, and it was dangerous and daring in a way that many men found intimidating and therefore admired those willing to do it. It was only when mining was poorly paid - as at times it was - that it lacked prestige. (2/2)

Comment: Greeks tended to do all their mining using slaves when they could afford that, and such slaves didn't last.